# Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$BigTextStyle', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx, admob

I've followed this [tutorial](http://www.norakomi.com/tutorial_admob_introduction.php) in order to install admob on my libgdx game. Yet I'm keep getting this error everytime I run my android libgx game.  Anyone know how to solve it?

**Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$BigTextStyle', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.**

Comment: Do you have google play services installed?

Comment: Yes i do and it's from the following link: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_8298000_r28.zip